# What is the [x] in a "Function()[x]" in Python?

Tags: python, function

I only want to know what is the meaning of [x] in a function (In general, not about the code that I will show), which I always think as a list but found nothing about it.

I will show two codes that I have seen using it, the first one is using PyTorch Library (Convolution):

1. Short one:

   ```
   x.size()[0]
   ```

   Long one:

   ```
   def forward(self, x):
       conv_out = self.conv(x).view(x.size()[0], -1)
       return self.fc(conv_out)
   ```
2. The second one is using GYM library for RL, but also part of the code above:

Short one:

```
    assert env.unwrapped.get_action_meanings()[1] == 'FIRE'
```

Long one:

```
    def __init__(self, env=None):
        """For environments where the user need to press FIRE for the game to start."""
        super(FireResetEnv, self).__init__(env)
        assert env.unwrapped.get_action_meanings()[1] == 'FIRE'
        assert len(env.unwrapped.get_action_meanings()) >= 3
```

I don't want to know why they are using the `function()[x]`, I only want to know what is the `[x]` in general.

Thank for the answer.

Comment: `x.size()` evidently returns a list (array) and the `[0]` indexes the first element. Similar logic applies to the other examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` is the indexing operator in Python.

If you have a list or tuple `l`, `l[n]` means the `n`th element of it.

If you have a dictionary d, `d[x]` means the element whose key is `x`.

If you have a string `s`, s[n]`means the`n`th character in the string.

Some other datatypes define their own indexing functions, but they generally implement the same idea, possibly extending it (Numpy arrays allow you to use a tuple to perform multi-dimensional indexing and slicing).

If you put `[x]` after a function call, it performs the indexing on whatever the function returns.

```
y = function()[x]
```

is equivalent to

```
temp = function()
y = temp[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

The **[x]** that comes after the several types of input you describe is simply an index reference. It can apply to lists, tuples or dicts, depending on how you use them. For example:

```
z = np.zeros((2, 3)) #Creates a numpy array of zeros with size (2, 3)
print(z.size()) #Outputs (2, 3)
print(z.size()[0]) #outputs the 0th index of the tuple
print(z.size()[2]) #Returns index error as it is out of range
```

The same applies for lists and dicts but comes with varied problems. Most of the time, for functions, this is used only if you know what is the format of the return value and you only need a part of it.

Hope this helps.